# Fixing the video container size so the video doesn't stretch beyond it

Tags: html, css, video

I'm using [this](http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/cube-portfolio-responsive-jquery-grid-plugin/full_screen_preview/6372959?_ga=1.253197068.425854822.1477833372) plugin to display a video grid. Clicking a grid item pops up a video container where you can view a video. The issue I'm having using this plugin is, it works great for videos with aspect ratio 16:9. However, videos with height greater than the width, the video container stretches vertically and goes off screen and the video looks choppy and zoomed. How do I fix the size of the container so the video doesn't get stretched.

Here's the HTML for the video container:

```
<div class="cbp-popup-wrap cbp-popup-lightbox cbp-popup-lightbox-isIframe cbp-popup-ready" data-action="close" style="display: block;"><div class="cbp-popup-content">
  <a href="/video/179/sdvsdd.aspx"></a>
  <div class="cbp-popup-lightbox-title">
    <a href="/video/179/sdvsdd.aspx">sdvsdd
      <div class="cbp-popup-lightbox-iframe">
        <video controls="controls" height="auto" style="width: 100%">
          <source src="/stream/stream.ashx?f=p1b0aqijn7115fsud1o2n9m53i83_5.mp4&amp;u=kahmed&amp;max=3000" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cbp-popup-loadingBox">
  </div>
  <div class="cbp-popup-navigation-wrap">
    <div class="cbp-popup-navigation">
      <div class="cbp-popup-close" title="Close (Esc arrow key)" data-action="close"></div>
      <div class="cbp-popup-next" title="Next (Right arrow key)" data-action="next" style="display: block;">
      </div>
      <div class="cbp-popup-prev" title="Previous (Left arrow key)" data-action="prev" style="display: block;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what the video with height greater than width looks like:

[image]

Video with the right size looks like this (which is what I want for the above video)

[image]

If I make the height of `<video>` 100%, the video disappears. Setting it to a fixed height shrinks the video but the container stays the same size as shown below:

[image]

The guy from support instructed me to use the below property:

```
.cbp-popup-lightbox-isIframe .cbp-popup-content {
width: 35% !important;
```

}

Which makes the video look as below

[image]

But this is not what I want. I want the container to remain the fixed size and make the video fit into the container. I have been stuck on this for a while now and haven't figured out how to do it.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<video width="400" height="300" ... 

<iframe width="400" height="300" ... 

<object width="400" height="300" ...

<embed width="400" height="300" ...
```

link:-https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

**or**

```
.videowrapper {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videowrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried setting the video height but that shrinks the video while the frame remains the same size. I want frame to shrink along with the video

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap offers some classes allowing you to keep your videos within their container and with the correct dimensions. Those classes are `embed-responsive` and then either `embed-responsive-16by9` or `embed-responsive-4by3`.
See [this](https://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/zbKAD/).